# Directory Services 400,000 users query export

Tags: active-directory

I wrote an application that will export all the users from the Active Directory and write them to a database. the problem is that on an Active Directory with 20,000 Users this method below works just fine, but on Active Directory with 400,000 it gets stuck until it crushes. I have defined the PageSize but it doesn't help. how can I solve this issue?

```
public List<string> GetAllUsers()
{
    List<string> AllUsers = new Lists<string>();

    DirectoryEntry deDomain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP//xxxxx.xxxx,username,password);
    DirectorySearcher dsSercher = new DirectorySearcher(deDomain);

    dsSearcher.filter = "(objectclass=user)";
    dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectclass");
    dsSearcher.PageSize = 1000;

    SearchResultCollection srcResults = dsSearcher.FindAll();

    foreach (SearchResult currResult in srcResults)
    {
        if (currResult.Properties["objectclass"].Count == 4 &&
            currResult.Properties["objectclass"][0].ToString() == "top" && 
            currResult.Properties["objectclass"][0].ToString() == "person" && 
            currResult.Properties["objectclass"][0].ToString() == "organizationalPerson" && 
            currResult.Properties["objectclass"][0].ToString() == "user")
            {
               AllUsers.Add(currResult.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
            }
    }
    return (AllUsers);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding some debugging to it so you can see exactly where it is stalling?  My guess is the FindAll() is taking quite a while, and then looping through each result would take a while.

Comment: That should probably be 0, 1, 2, 3 not 0, 0, 0, 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the predicates in your `if` statement ever evaluate to `true`, you're maintaining a list of **all 400,000 users** in memory. There would be a lot of paging going on here. Additionally, if `List` requires contiguous memory then you are probably not going to get it.

Try converting the function to use [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Also, post on a programming forum for other answers. This is SuperUser.

EDIT: I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/12/20/63581.aspx). It appears that `FindAll` literally *finds all*, the `PageSize` is internal to the operation.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx#sdspintro_topic5_pagedsearch  - How to do a paged search.

Comment: When I change the PageSize the number of the results changes with it.

Comment: Perhaps it runs out of memory at different stages? E.g. PageSize = 1000 fails at 199,000 results but PageSize = 10000 fails at 190,000. In this case there's only enough memory for 199,999 results.